# Is it possible to use casperjs to test your website if it can handle many users?

Tags: testing, casperjs, automated-tests

I need to test my website if it can handle 100 or more users concurrently, Is it possible to do it by casperjs? if yes, how will i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not really.

CasperJS runs on PhantomJS (or SlimerJS). So you can only have one session per CasperJS script. You could use multiple `casper` instances if your site doesn't need sessions (i.e. doesn't have a login), but since PhantomJS is single threaded, that won't get you much concurrency.

You would need to start 100 CasperJS processes with the same script to simulate that many users, but then you run into hardware problems. Let's say one CasperJS process takes 50 MB of RAM. Your machine would need at least 5 GB of memory. Then there are the context switches because of so many processes, which wouldn't make it very concurrent.

You would need a cluster of machines with at most 16 CasperJS processes each. You would then need to synchronize them all (i.e. with the [webserver module](http://phantomjs.org/api/webserver/)).